Prove that the average of the numbers $n\sin(n^{\circ}),n=2^{\circ},4^{\circ},6^{\circ},\ldots,180^{\circ}$ is $\cot(1)$.

Prove that the average of the numbers $n\sin(n^{\circ}),n=2,4,6,\ldots,180^{\circ}$ is $\cot(1^{\circ})$.

I am trying to use complex numbers to solve the given problem. We can write $$\sin(n^{\circ})=\cfrac{e^{in\frac{\pi}{180}}-e^{-in\frac{\pi}{180}}}{2i}.$$
I am unable to use any ideas to find the average in an elegant way using complex numbers. Please note, I do not want to see any telescopic methods to solve the problem.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I am not posting the full solution, as the OP didn't even try to read the comments and edit their post. Other users, particularly @Gwen, have to interpret the question for us.

Let $$S=2\sin2+4\sin4+\cdots+180\sin180$$
Use the trigonometric identity, $\sin(x)=\sin(\pi-x)$ and rewrite the summation as $$S=180(\sin2+\sin4+\cdots+\sin88)+90\sin90$$
I hope you can easily evaluate the expression under the brackets.
